# Ldap and Kerberos username correlation

Tags: ldap, kerberos

I am proxy between user and DB.
I got users list from Ldap.
I need to find the user connected using Kerberos to my proxy in the ldap users list.
What is data in Kerberos ticket that could be used for this search.
Or what is the way to implement such search?
Window, AD, MS Sql.

Answer (score 0):

SID could be used as a unique identifier. 
DB holds it but a binary representation of the SID. 
SID should be converted to the string format.
In ldap it's "objectSID"